# d3 - improper y axis tick marks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am plotting a simple d3 bar chart. Everything is fine. But The Y axis tick labels are incorrect. 
I want the labels ranging from 0 to 100%, but it displays something larger than 5000%.

What am I doing wrong. I am guessing that my variable yAxis has to be modified. But, I am confused as to how to do it ?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="height:100px;"> </div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 100]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + " out of 630 patients </span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

My data.tsv file has the following contents:

```
letter  frequency
Asian   4
African-American    96
White   441
Hispanic    81
Other   11
```

Comment: You need to convert the strings to numbers: `data.forEach(function(d) { d.frequency = +d.frequency; })`.

Comment: Is there a specific place where I should place this code ? Also, I have a function by the name type() which converts the frequency to a number (its at the very bottom)

Comment: Where's... your... head... at...? You are missing the `<head>` tag in your document.

Comment: How does that matter? My graph is being plotted. Its just that my y axis labels are not proper

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman Yes, at the beginning of the `d3.tsv` callback.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Didn't help. I still get the same output.

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman You're using the format function incorrectly. You probably want just `.tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the y axis to percent do the following:

My approach is to make the frequency into percent.

```
//this will calculate the sum of frequency
var sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return +d.frequency;});
//this will convert the frequency into percent
data.forEach(function(d){ d.frequency = (d.frequency/sum)*100});
```

Give the y axis domain from 0% to 100% like this

```
  y.domain([0, 100]);
```

For the y axis you can give the percent like this(don't need to convert into percent since we have already done that above):

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/89aZWujDnqLmxTrF02Nz?p=preview).